# Change url that ApiHttpService get

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http

I have this code

```
constructor(apiService: ApiHttpService) {
    this.aService = apiService;
  }
      
public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.aService
          .get(`/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`, headers.headersJson)
          .pipe(
            map((response: JSON) => {
              return response;
            })
          );
      }
```

and it returns response only when the port is 8080 used, but I want it to work also on other ports as 3000 also when I deploy the code to a server as https://dashboard.something.com/... but now it keeps reading wrong and giving this error

zone-evergreen.js:2845          GET http://localhost:8080/assets/i18n/ar.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

How can I resolve this? How to read it from the file of the deployed server?

Answer (score 0):

Angular provides an `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` (see [here](https://angular.io/guide/build) for a lot more info) file where you can store environment-dependent data, like the URL of your server. Depending on your build configuration, it will replace content of `environment.ts` with `environment.prod.ts` content at build time.

Example:

```
// environment.ts

export const environment = {
  production: false,
  serverUrl: ''
};
```

```
// environment.prod.ts

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  serverUrl: 'https://the-location-to-my.server'
};
```

In your code, you can use the environment variables like this:

```
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

// ... other stuff

constructor(apiService: ApiHttpService) {
    this.aService = apiService;
  }
      
public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.aService
           // here we use the environment to determine the serverUrl!
          .get(`${environment.serverUrl}/assets/i18n/${lang}.json`, headers.headersJson) 
          .pipe(
            map((response: JSON) => {
              return response;
            })
          );
      }
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped a little knowing my problem.